# Data Fetching Using useEffect() And useCallback In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, usecallback

### Issue

I'm looking for the most optimal way to fetch data using `useEffect()` when the fetch function is used in more than one place.

### Situation

Currently, I have a parent component (`ItemContainer`) and a child component (`SearchBar`). `ItemContainer` should fetch the all the possible list of items using `getItemList()` functions. I'm executing this function within the `useEffect()` during the first render, and  also passing it down to `SearchBar` component, so that when a user submits a search term, it will update `itemList` state by triggering `getItemList()` in `ItemContainer`.

This actually works just as I expected. However, my issue is that

1. I'm not really sure whether it is okay to define `getItemList()` outside the `useEffect()` in this kind of situation. From what I've been reading (blog posts, react official docs) it is generally recommended that data fetching function should be defined inside the `useEffect()`, although there could be some edge cases. I'm wondering if my case applies as this edge cases.
2. Is it okay to leave the dependency array empty in `useCallback`? I tried filling it out using `searchTerm`, `itemList`, but none of them worked - and I'm quite confused why this is so.

I feel bad that I don't fully understand the code that I wrote. I would appreciate if any of you could enlighten me with what I'm missing here...

#### ItemContainer

```js
    const ItemContainer = () => {
        const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
    
        const getItemList = useCallback( async (searchTerm) => {
            const itemListRes = await Api.getItems(searchTerm);
            setItemList(itemListRes)
        }, []);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            getItemList();
        }, [getItemList]);
    
        return (
            <main>
                <SearchBar search={getItemList} />
                <ItemList itemList={itemList} />
            </main>
        )
    }
```

#### SearchBar

```js
const SearchBar = ({ search })  => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        search(searchTerm);
        setSearchTerm('');
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                placeholder='Enter search term...'
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button>Search</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my answers.

1. Yes, it is okay. What's inside `useCallback` is "frozen" respect to
   the many `ItemConteiner` function calls that may happen. Since the
   `useCallback` content accesses only `setItemList`, which is also a
   frozen handler, there'll be no problems.
2. That's also correct, because an empty array means "dependent to
   nothing". In other words, the callback is created once and keeps
   frozen for all the life of the `ItemContainer`.

Instead, this is something weird:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getItemList();
    }, [getItemList]);
```

It works, but it has a very little sense. The `getItemList` is created once only, so why make an `useEffect` depending to something never changes?

Make it simpler, by running once only:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getItemList();
    }, []);
```